Can someone help me out with an unassigned local variable?
I'm currently doing a project for my programming class in college, and I am almost done with it. Unfortunately, I seem to have a problem with my code.
I am a beginner coder. The issue lies in the line where the code says if (totalbmi <= 18.5m).
// Input Variables
decimal height;     // The height of the user
decimal weight;     // The weight of the user
decimal totalbmi;   // The total BMI after calculating the height and weight
string weightcategory = "YOU ARE:\n"; //Shows the user if they are overweight, underweight, or normal.
string gender = "YOUR GENDER IS: \n"; // Shows the user their gender after finishing calculations

// Validate that numeric information is in the textboxes.
if (decimal.TryParse(heightTextBox.Text, out height) && decimal.TryParse(weightTextBox.Text, out weight))
{
     totalbmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height); //This is the caulculation to find the total bmi.
     finalBMILabel.Text = totalbmi.ToString("n"); //This is where the final BMI will be placed after the calculation
}

// Tell the user their general weight category.
if (totalbmi <= 18.5m)
{
     weightcategory += "UNDERWEIGHT\n";
}
else if (totalbmi >= 18.5m && totalbmi <24.9m)
{
     weightcategory += "NORMAL WEIGHT\n";
}
else if (totalbmi >=25m && totalbmi < 29.9m)
{
     weightcategory += "OVERWEIGHT\n";
}

I tried my best to edit the variable type as well as look at online tutorials but with no such luck.

What's the value of totalbmi if your parsing fails?

The problem is that if the first if is skipped (because one of the TryParse fail), totalbmi remains unassigned. You have to decide what's the behavior you expect in this case from the next if (totalbmi <= 18.5m) and either initialize it to some default value or change the logic.

Move the second if inside the first one.

You've defined totalbmi without an initial value, and if the first if block is skipped, it will still be undefined when you go and inspect it to determine what to show to the user.
There are lots of ways to fix this - here's two I would look into:
(1) Just simply pre-initialize the totalbmi variable to a value when declaring it, and then checking for that pre-defined value to handle display:
// Input Variables
decimal totalbmi = -1;   // initialize to "-1", signifying "undefined"

// Validate that numeric information is in the textboxes.
if (decimal.TryParse(heightTextBox.Text, out height) && decimal.TryParse(weightTextBox.Text, out weight))
{
     totalbmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height); //This is the caulculation to find the total bmi.
     finalBMILabel.Text = totalbmi.ToString("n"); //This is where the final BMI will be placed after the calculation
}

// check for "undefined"
if (totalbmi <= 0.0m)
{
    weightcategory += "UNDEFINED\n";
}
else if (totalbmi <= 18.5m)
{
     weightcategory += "UNDERWEIGHT\n";
}
.....

(2) Move the display of the result of the totalbmi calculation into the same block, where you can be sure to have a value:
// Input Variables
decimal totalbmi = -1;   // initialize to "-1", signifying "undefined"

// Validate that numeric information is in the textboxes.
if (decimal.TryParse(heightTextBox.Text, out height) && decimal.TryParse(weightTextBox.Text, out weight))
{
    totalbmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height); //This is the caulculation to find the total bmi.
    finalBMILabel.Text = totalbmi.ToString("n"); //This is where the final BMI will be placed after the calculation
     
    // Tell the user their general weight category.
    if (totalbmi <= 18.5m)
    {
         weightcategory += "UNDERWEIGHT\n";
    }
    else if (totalbmi >= 18.5m && totalbmi <24.9m)
    {
         weightcategory += "NORMAL WEIGHT\n";
    }
    else if (totalbmi >=25m && totalbmi < 29.9m)
    {
         weightcategory += "OVERWEIGHT\n";
    }
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot calculate total BMI");
}

